# Where can I find character constants in C#?

Tags: c#

I currently have this code:

```
if (e.KeyChar == (char)8)
{

}
```

What I would like is the C# equivalent of the vbBackspace constant.  Is there such a thing in C#?

Example:

```
if (e.KeyChar == SomeNameSpace.Something.Backspace)
{

}
```

Comment: Seriously, you accept the answer posted four minutes later with only two votes...?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know it was wrong to vote for the one with the least number of votes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (e.KeyChar == Keys.Back)
{

}
```

Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx) for more info